# continuation-local-storage loses values after await/async call?

Tags: javascript, async-await, continuation-local-storage

I am trying to use [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) to persist some context value untill few ( 1-2 )async tasks are complete. Below is my code & it's sample output,

```
var request = require('request');
var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');


function main() {
    var writer = cls.createNamespace('test');
    writer.run(async function () {
        writer.set('key', 'test_value');
        console.log('cls value: ' + cls.getNamespace('test').get('key'));

        let r1 = await apiCall();
        console.log('cls value: ' + cls.getNamespace('test').get('key'));

        let r2 = await apiCall();
        console.log('cls value: ' + cls.getNamespace('test').get('key'));

        let r3 = await apiCall();
        console.log('cls value: ' + cls.getNamespace('test').get('key'));
      });
}

async function apiCall() {
    return await request.get('https://localhost:8080/');
}

main();
```

The output of above app.js,

```
cls value: test_value
cls value: undefined
cls value: undefined
cls value: undefined
```

So after the first call to an `async` function using `await`, my value got lost, It is undefined. How do I use `continuation-local-storage` for multiple `await`'s on `async` function calls without losing the value set on `continuation-local-storage`?

***Update***

Check out this Github issue https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage/issues/133 it recommends using [cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked).

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

Check out this Github issue https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage/issues/133 it recommends using cls-hooked.

Answer (score 1):

**Update to answer on April 2021**

Just to add on here, if you're using node 12.17.0 or 13.10.0 and above, it is better to use the native `AsyncLocalStorage` which is much faster than cls-hooked.

I've also written an alternative to cls-hooked, which gives provide those who are using node v8.12.0 and above a consistent API to `AsyncLocalStorage`. My implementation is slightly different to cls-hooked and is slightly faster and fix some of the current bug as well.

A small micro-benchmark here
https://github.com/Darkripper214/ALS-CLS-Benchmark

You can take a look here.
https://github.com/Darkripper214/ALS-Context